# Select One element in a subquery LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using LINQ to pull data from a database and have a question about pulling an object from a subquery. This is the class that I am pulling:

```
public class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        SerialNumbers = new HashSet<SerialNumbers>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The User's Unique Id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Users name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Users email. This can be null/empty string
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SerialNumbers> SerialNumbers { get; set; }

}
```

How do I select the first element from the Serial Numbers collection and not the whole collection itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a DataTransferObject and map to it:

```
context.Users.Select(x => new UserDto
{ 
    Id = x.Id, 
    Name = x.Name, 
    Email = x.Email, 
    SerialNumber = x.SerialNumbers.FirstOrDefault() 
});
```

Comment: Ok, I took your advice and created a DTO and this is what I have, IEnumerable<UserDTO> users = databaseConnection.Users.Select(x => new UserDTO
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Email = x.Email,
                serialNumber = x.SerialNumbers.FirstOrDefault().Id,       
            });                                                                                                            For some reason, I am getting a null pointer exception though, Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I was just missing a null checkon the SerialNumbers.FirstOrDefault()?.Name. It'd be a long day and wasn't thinking straight. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
var serial = context.Users.FirstOrDefault().SerialNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I want to return all Users all having one serial number

Comment: var users = (databaseConnection.Users
                            .OrderBy(c => c.Name))